# Is there any potential bug in async code that work with DB?

Tags: dart

I wrote next code that run generation and insert SQL in DB db by incoming JSON.

```
  Future<dbEnums> matchAndInsert(String section, Map jsonMap) async {
    tableToInsert = "notifications"; 
    try {
        db.saveOriginalJson(jsonMap);
        await db.KVToTableInsert(tableToInsert, jsonMap);
```

`KVToTableInsert` inside store some temp data (like names of nested tables that I am extracting from JSON).

The request handler is done in next way:

```
  app.post('/foo', (req, res) async {
    dbEnums insertResult = await matchQuery.foo("tablename", req.body);
```

This code work fine if I am sending data to handler from one thread (desktop C# app that can work in n threads). But it crush if I am trying to do it with few threads of parser (different root and nested tables). In error I am seeing that it's try to insert data to table2 while some fields are from table1.

Do I an using async wrong? Because it's look like data in method is overlapping?
How to fix code?

Am I right understand that I am overwriting field in `saveOriginalJson` before `KVToTableInsert` is complete? How to fix it?

```
 db.saveOriginalJson(jsonMap);
 await db.KVToTableInsert(tableToInsert, jsonMap);
```

P.S. more code if it needed https://gist.github.com/bubnenkoff/517e485757955a52494280977a85fb66

Comment: With multiple threads, are you meaning multiple isolates? If not, are you sharing your `db` instance in multiple async methods? If yes, do multiple of these call `saveOriginalJson``?

Comment: The reason is I smell a possible design problem in the `saveOriginalJson` method since it allows you do change `jsonMapOriginal` in the DB object while `KVToTableInsert` are awaiting on the call on `KVToTableInsert` inside `KVToTableInsert`.

Comment: > If not, are you sharing your db instance in multiple async methods?

Yes. I do share. 

> If yes, do multiple of these call `saveOriginalJson`
Yes it's possible

So I should do `jsonMapOriginal` from another place?

Comment: Can you try stop using `saveOriginalJson` and give the `jsonMap` as parameter to `KVToTableInsert`? This should stop the risk of the variable be changed by other calls. You need to also change `KVToTableInsert` to send the `jsonMap` with it in the nested call inside `KVToTableInsert`.

Comment: Oh anther problem you have. You are not creating a copy of your `jsonMap` so `saveOriginalJson` are just saving a reference to the exact same instance of the map you are also give as parameter to `KVToTableInsert`. So when `KVToTableInsert` manipulates the map, you are also manipulating the map pointed by `jsonMapOriginal` since they are the same instance.

Comment: @julemand101 How to create a copy of `jsonMap`? What is correct syntax?

Comment: Depends on the structure of the map. I need more of your program before I can give an exact answer.